# Automating tasks for multiple files using R to rearrange source data files in the R working directory

Tags: r

I am new to R and currently learning how to automate work for files in a directory, currently I am trying with 5 sample CSV files with hourly sample data in every column for 24 hours in a directory. I am  trying to set some codes to organise the files to a suitable format for future so that I can read easily in R later. My files are in a strange format with 6 top rows with unnecessary data. I am trying to perform few tasks as follows:

Sample of my data file:

```
"w", "Fri 1 Jan", "123", "42", "12", "21"  
"w", "Sat 2 Jan", "23", "54", "62", "31"    
"w", "Sun 3 Jan", "13", "32", "22", "32"    
"w", "Mon 4 Jan", "153", "42", "52", "31"    
"w", "Tue 5 Jan", "13", "14", "67", "35"
```

- Task 1: ignore first 6 rows and start reading from 7th row
- Task 2: set columns heading to: “type”, “date”, “1”, “2”, “3”, “Sample”
- Task 3: Each of my file are with a file name similar to this: “605_E875071_N713451.csv” - I am trying to create 3 new separate columns with names: ID =”605” , Easting =”875071”, and Northing = “713451”
- Task 4: create some kind of loop to perform all these steps and save directly to the original file

I have tried to workout each step individually and so far I managed to find codes in the website to perform the tasks as below:

Task 1:

```
data = read.csv(file.choose (),  skip = 6 )`
```

Task 2:

```
colnames(data) = c(“type”, “date”, “1”, “2”, “3”, “Total”)
```

Task 3:

I am not sure how to separate in 3 different columns; so far what I have got can create an additional column and type the full name “605_E875071_N713451”:

```
read_csv_filename <- function(filename){ 
        ret <- read.csv(filename)    
        ret$Source <- filename     
        ret }  
     import.list <- ldply(filenames, read_csv_filename) 
             ldply(filenames, read_csv_filename)
```

What I am finally trying to achieve is as follows:

```
“type”, “date”,  "ID", "Easting", "Northing", “1”, “2”, “3”, “Total”  
"w", "Fri 1 Jan",”605” ,”875071”,  “713451”,"123", "42", "12", "21"  
"w", "Sat 2 Jan",”605” ,”875071”,  “713451”,"23", "54", "62", "31"    
"w", "Sun 3 Jan",”605” ,”875071”,  “713451”,"13", "32", "22", "32"    
"w", "Mon 4 Jan",”605” ,”875071”,  “713451”,"153", "42", "52", "31"    
"w", "Tue 5 Jan", ”605” ,”875071”, “713451”,"13", "14", "67", "35"
```

and lastly, I am wondering if there is any way that I could automate these steps to perform the tasks automatically and do the steps for all the 5 files in the directory and save back to the original files?

I would be really grateful for any of your kind advice and guidance, thanks

Comment: WARNING: You are using an editor that inserts "smart quotes". That will cause you no end of confusion. You really cannot use MSWord for code editing unless you turn off all the magic stuff it thinks you want.

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't know, i m very new in this site and still learning how to use it properly, thanks for letting me know

Comment: My warning was not about your use of this site, but rather about what you use to create code for R. If you try to stick those right and left quotes into R you will create the most obscure errors known to man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're on the right track for steps 1 and 2.  However, to automate the process, you'll want to use `list.files()` rather than `file.choose()`.

Also, I would suggest avoiding column names that start with or are only a number.  name them 'one' 'two' 'three' or 'V1' etc. instead so you can use the `$` to explore them later.

For task 3, look at `strsplit`:

```
out <- strsplit(filename,'_')
```

then you can grab pieces and do what you will with them:

```
gsub('N', '', lapply(out, '[', 2)) # should get your Easting column
```

As far as your last question, the simple answer is no.  the more complicated answer is that its complicated!  Unless the files are quite big (1e7 rows or more) or your machine has very little ram, you should be alright reading each file into R (and therefore memory) and writing them back out.

On somewhat of a side note: As you work on this, feel free to ask single specific questions (ideally with some sample of your data so we can reproduce what you're working on) and you'll get better and more exact answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try your suggestion tomorrow morning when I am back in uni. my data frame  is 28 X 400 but I have few hundred files in the directory. I have tried to copy and paste a original sample data file but I am not sure why but some reason when I paste a table it changes all the format and not sure how to separate cells, so I typed up some random data.